# Datatime series plotting with different start date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have some DB tables saved in different CSV files/DataFrame with months of data each DF.
With data a graphic is plot with matplotlib.  It plots all data when any table for Rank1 has all values populated however if Rank1 table has few rows the graphic only take as much row as table have it.

[image]

I extracted some DF sample for showing the issue, time column is datatime series which links the DF:

```
df1 = [index,time],
[0,2020-03-21 01:20:00],
[1,2020-03-21 02:20:00],
[2,2020-03-21 03:20:00],
[3,2020-03-21 04:20:00],
[4,2020-03-21 05:20:00],
[5,2020-03-21 06:20:00],
[6,2020-03-21 07:20:00]]

df2 = [[index,time,8LYCUG89Q],
[1,2020-03-21 02:20:00,5939],
[2,2020-03-21 03:20:00,6000],
[3,2020-03-21 04:20:00,6000]]

df3 = [[index,time,P99YQPU0R],
[0,2020-03-20 23:20:00,5709],
[1,2020-03-21 00:20:00,5709],
[2,2020-03-21 01:20:00,5709],
[3,2020-03-21 02:20:00,5709],
[4,2020-03-21 03:20:00,5709],
[5,2020-03-21 04:20:00,5709],
[6,2020-03-21 05:20:00,5709]]

df4 = [[index,time,90QCVGVPG],
[0,2020-03-20 23:20:00,5611],
[1,2020-03-21 00:20:00,NaN],
[2,2020-03-21 01:20:00,5611],
[3,2020-03-21 02:20:00,5611],
[4,2020-03-21 03:20:00,NaN],
[5,2020-03-21 04:20:00,5611],
[6,2020-03-21 05:20:00,5611]]

df5 = [[index,time,LLQ9URY], 
[0,2020-03-20 23:20:00,NaN],
[1,2020-03-21 00:20:00,5603],
[2,2020-03-21 01:20:00,5603],
[3,2020-03-21 02:20:00,5603],
[4,2020-03-21 03:20:00,5576],
[5,2020-03-21 04:20:00,5576],
[6,2020-03-21 05:20:00,NaN]]

df6 = [[index,time,UV0R8U0],
[0,2020-03-20 23:20:00,5545],
[1,2020-03-21 00:20:00,5545],
[2,2020-03-21 01:20:00,5545],
[3,2020-03-21 02:20:00,5545],
[4,2020-03-21 03:20:00,5545],
[5,2020-03-21 04:20:00,5545],
[6,2020-03-21 05:20:00,5545]]
```

for DF result I am expecting to get a DF with NaN values for Rank1 if table actually is not populated in time column from DF1, such as:

```
index   time                8LYCUG89Q   P99YQPU0R   90QCVGVPG   LLQ9URY UV0R8U0
0       2020-03-20 23:20:00 NaN         5709        5611        NaN     5545
1       2020-03-21 00:20:00 NaN         5709        NaN         5603    5545
2       2020-03-21 01:20:00 NaN         5709        5611        5603    5545
3       2020-03-21 02:20:00 NaN         5709        5611        5603    5545
4       2020-03-21 03:20:00 5939        5709        NaN         5576    5545
5       2020-03-21 04:20:00 6000        5709        5611        5576    5545
6       2020-03-21 05:20:00 6000        5709        5611        NaN     5545
```

The snippet for getting final DF is

```
colnametop = ['8LYCUG89Q', 'P99YQPU0R', '90QCVGVPG', 'LLQ9URY', 'UV0R8U0']
finaltop_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time'])
for i in colnametop:
    memdata = pd.read_csv("file_path",i),usecols=['time','data'],parse_dates=['time']).rename(columns={'data':i})
    finaltop_df = pd.merge(finaltop_df,memdata,on='time')
finaltop_df
```

The result is the DF below which I commented above is taking only the data on DF2 and dropped any datatime from df1 which is not populated even the Rank2~Rank4 have it.

The result in final graphic is lost on data presentation.

```
index   time                8LYCUG89Q   P99YQPU0R   90QCVGVPG   LLQ9URY UV0R8U0
0       2020-03-21 03:20:00 5939        5709        NaN         5576    5545
1       2020-03-21 04:20:00 6000        5709        5611        5576    5545
2       2020-03-21 05:20:00 6000        5709        5611        NaN     5545
```

Thanks for your hints

Comment: Thank you for providing sample data and expected output. +1

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of dataframes and then use pd.concat.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]  # You need a list of dataframes
df_list2 = []
for df in df_list:
    # df = df.reset_index()  # Maybe you have to reset your index first because of your first dataframe with no data.
    df = df.set_index('time')
    df2_list2.append(df)
df = pd.concat(df_list2, sort=True)
```

Comment: I received `KeyError: 0` in list comprehension. I extracted expression for DF1
 `pd.DataFrame.from_records(df1[1:],index='time',columns=df1[0])` and got same error.  **is that what you tried to process?**

Comment: My mistake. I had to rebuild your data. For that I needed .from_records. You just have to make sure that every dataframe has time as an index. I have modified my answer.